# Restart my acceleration calculator in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, calculator

I made a simply python acceleration calculator, but the problem I'm having is getting the program to return to the beginning or exit. I want the user to be able hit '1' and restart the calculator or hit '2' and have the program exit. I can’t seem to figure out how to run my main function after the program has went through the equation, any suggestions? Thanks.

```
class equation():

    def main():
        Calc()
        while True:
            restart = input("Would you like to run again? If yes press '1' if you wish to Exit press '2'")
            if restart==1:
                Calc()
            else:
                print "Goodbye"
                break

    print "What is your Velocity: "
    v = float(input()) #m/s
    print "What is your Intial Velocity: "
    u = float(input()) #m/s
    print "What is the time: "
    t = float(input()) #Seconds
    aa = v-u
    answer = aa/t

eq=equation()

print "Your Acceleration is: ", eq.answer, "m/s^2"

print eq.main
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indenting is wrong, the whole `if` has to be indented 4 spaces, and add a `break` in the `else`.

Also the input receives a string, not a number.

Comment: `if restart=='1':` and it should work, and if it's Python 2,7 you use `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I have understood your question and I would also suggest you to always write a basic program and then move on to complex logic and keep building on that platform that you have set.

So I wrote a basic program that would get user input to decide to calculate or exit. If it is calculate then it would get two numbers from the user and would do addition and return back to wait whether to exit or continue doing calculations.

## !/usr/bin/python

```
class equation:


        def calculate(self):
                print 'Enter the first number'
                input1 = int(raw_input())
                print 'Enter the second number'
                input2 = int(raw_input())
                result = input1 + input2
                print result

        def mainfun(self):
                while True:
                        print 'Enter 1 for calculate operation and any to exit'
                        userInput = str(raw_input())
                        if userInput=='1':
                                self.calculate()
                        else:
                                print 'Good bye'
                                break

operation = equation()

operation.mainfun()
```

I have tested the code and it works.